# Override a filter property

Tags: css, filter

I have a body tag with `-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%)`

Inside body I need div.an-alternative to be without grayscale. 
I tried to add `-webkit-filter: grayscale(0)` to this div, but nothing changed.

If I add to body `font-size: 16px` and then add to div `font-size: 20px`, text inside div will be 20px. Why this principle doesn't work with filter?

My code:

```
html 
<body class="different classes here" style="-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); background-attachment: scroll;"> ... 
<div class="an-alternative"> ... </div>
</body>

css
body .an-alternative {
margin-left: 240px;
-webkit-filter: none;
filter: none;
background-color: red;
```

}

And this is simple jsfiddle example which doesnt work too - https://jsfiddle.net/28yovw0k/1/

Comment: But example with font-size will work, right?

Comment: Right, because `font-size` can be changed by descendants.

Comment: Post your HTML/CSS please - also instead of using `grayscale(0)`, try `-webkit-filter: none;` instead

Comment: `filter` like `opacity` applied to parent is not overridable by CSS on children.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've recently encountered a similar issue. There are 2 things to note here in my answer, the element you're trying to override needs a higher CSS specificity as well as the filter property is here being applied to all children divs. So as Paulie_D said, you cannot override a parent's filter. But this solution does allow you to "remove" the grey filter.

```
.gray div {
    width: 100px;
    filter: grayscale(0.8);
    height: 100px;
}
.gray .red {
    background: red;
    filter: grayscale(0);
}
.blue {
    background: blue;
}
.green {
    background: green;
}
```